# Using HTML forms with a PHP script

Tags: php, html

How do I reference a PHP file when submitting a form? I am using a text editor, so nothing fancy.
This is code is not working for me:

```
<html>  
    <body>  
        <form action="MAILTO:example@google.com">  
            <input>  
        </form> 
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: `<form action="a_php_file.php" method="post">`?

Comment: Did you even try to look it up at all? And text editors are how all HTML/PHP is written...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reference a PHP file when submitting a form"? And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: where would I put the php file

Comment: you should spend a few moments learning the basics of php (http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)

Comment: What!? On a server? Sorry, I really don't understand what you mean. Marc B wrote how you send the form data to "a_php_file.php" using the POST method. Is this what you want? Do you want to use the data submitted on this "a_php_file.php"?

Comment: You also never end the `<input>` tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action attribute of the form tag directs the browser to where you want to send your form data. To direct the browser to a PHP script, just change the action attribute in your code to the PHP script you'd like to send your data to.

```
<form action="my_php_file.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not PHP. In fact, it does not make any sense. `matilo:email@derp.com` is simply a link that opens your brower's default email client.

As Marc B posted as a comment, you can reference any file (like for example PHP) in the `action`-argument. In this file you will have all your form-fields available in the `$_POST`-variable.

If you want to send an e-mail you need to check out the `mail` function (http://www.php.net/mail). Just want to point out that there is no built in function that will send your form as a email (it looks like this is what you want). You'll either have to make your own code or use a library that does this.

Comment: i would but it says "you can accept this answer in 4 min

Comment: No worries, I got all the time in the world :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp